# Java: Inheritance of generic Node and Tree

Tags: java, inheritance

Got the following problem:
I'm using my own Tree class which is general. Another class which, a contact list, is inheriting from that Tree class. The reason I'm doing it this way is that there are other classes which will all need the same tree functionality, but they serve different purposes.

The Node is also a generic one and also inherits to special node types, like phone list, email contact list, etc.

In the Tree class there are some methods which use a local variable `Node`. In the contact list tree I need this same variable to be a `Contact` (which inherits from Node). When I use one of the methods inside contact list it defines the root node as `Node` and not as `Contact`, so it uses the generic Node not the one inheriting.

This is how it looks like:

```
public class Tree {

  Node root;

  public void insert( String x ) {
        root = insert( x, root );
 }
```

This is the contact list (root is of type `Contact` (which extends Node):

```
public class ContactList extends Tree {

Contact root;
```

And this is `Node`:

```
public class Node {

String idString;
    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    public Node() {}

    public Node(String idString) {
        this.idString = idString;
    }

}
```

How can I tell that inherited method insert not to use the local `root` but the one from the inheriting class.

I tried to solve this inside the constructor of `ContactList`:

```
public ContactList() {
super.root = this.root;
}
```

Didn't work. I think it gets overwritten by the Tree class immediately, so what is the proper way to inherit generic node behavior?

Comment: You should be using Generics, with a `Node<Contact>`.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the root variable in `ContactList`. if a `Contact` is a `Node` you can assign it easily in Constructor or other methods of super-class `Tree`:

```
public class Tree {

  Node root;

  public Tree(Node root) {
    this.root = root; 
  }

  public void insert( String x ) {
        root = insert( x, root );
  }
}
```

and for `ContactList`:

```
public class ContactList extends Tree {

  public ContactList(Contact contact) {
    super(contact);
  }
...
}
```

assuming that `Contact extends Node`. now when you call the inherited method on a `ContactList` instance, the `Contact` instance will be used.

```
ContactList list = new ContactList(new Contact(...));
list.insert("X");
```

but if you want to remove inheritance relation between Contact and Node, you should use [Java Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) :

```
public class Tree<T> {
  T root;

  public void insert(T node) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then:

```
Tree contactTree = new Tree<Contact>();
...
contactTree.insert(Contact c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics. Modify Tree and Node to have the following generic types:

- `Tree<T extends Tree<T,N>,N extends Node<T,N>>`
- `Node<T extends Node<T,N>,N extends Node<T,N>>`

Then in their fields and methods use the generic types T and N only. This allows you to have f.e. the subclasses

- `ContactTree extends Tree<ContactTree,ContactNode>`
- `ContactNode extends Node<ContactTree,ContactNode>`

Keep in mind that if your ContactTree ends up not having any methods or fields, then a plain `Tree<N extends Node>` would suffice.

Comment: I tried your solution but it marks Node with the following error: Incorrect number of arguments for type Node<T,N>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <T>

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add another type parameter, fixed.

Comment: Now Node seems to work, but in Tree it says: Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Node<T,N>> of the type 
 Node<T,N>

Comment: It should be `Node<T extends Tree<T,N>,N extends Node<T,N>>`